# How can I fetch with the Pinterest api Ad-Data for Ads that had an ad-spent in a specific time frame?

Tags: pinterest, pinterest-api

We want to develop a Pinterest integration and we would like to fetch all ads that performed (had adspent) in a specific time range. Sadly the only way we see in the docs is to fetch all available ads first and then fetch with bookmarks they’re adspent. So a lot of api requests depending on the size of the Pinterest account.

Does somebody know an efficient solution?

Kind regards

Fetch ads from the Pinterest api and get all ads that spent in a time frame.